# Finding path in 2D array using BFS

Tags: java, arrays, breadth-first-search, maze

I should find all the possible path in a 2D array with the condition

- 0 Empty Spaces
- 1 Obstacles
- 2 Stations
- 3 Final Destination

Find the number of possible paths must:

- pass through exactly 4 stations which is number '2'
- the path will start from '0' at the upper left side of the matrices and end '3' which is the final destination at the bottom right side
- providing  the path can move adjacently (left, right, top, down), strictly not diagonally
- not allowed to walk past the obstacles which are labelled as ‘1'
- not allowed to walk past the visited number again in a single journey
- walk on '0' is allowed and walk on total 2 '2' is allowed
- use breath first search to find the possible path

start from this first '0'

```
0 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
2 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
0 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 
0 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 2 0 0 0 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 1 
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
2 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 3 < end at this '3'
```

I use BFS to handle and search this large data. However i dont know what is going wrong in my code because it does give the right amount of path that can be accessed following the conditions.

CODE:

```java
public class completePathFinder1 {            
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = readArrayFromFile("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\NetBeansProjectsDS\\assignment\\modified_array.txt");
        if (matrix != null) {
            List<List<int[]>> paths = findPossiblePaths(matrix);
            System.out.println("Number of possible paths: " + paths.size());
   
        }
    }

    public static List<List<int[]>> findPossiblePaths(int[][] matrix) {
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int cols = matrix[0].length;
        int gridSize = rows * cols;
        BitSet[] visited = new BitSet[gridSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
            visited[i] = new BitSet(5); // Track station count from 0 to 4
        }
        int[][] directions = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};

        List<List<int[]>> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        List<int[]> currentPath = new ArrayList<>();
        dfs(matrix, 0, 0, 0, visited, directions, currentPath, paths);
        return paths;
    }

    private static void dfs(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int stationCount, BitSet[] visited, int[][] directions,
                            List<int[]> currentPath, List<List<int[]>> paths) {
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int cols = matrix[0].length;
        int position = x * cols + y;

        if (x == rows - 1 && y == cols - 1 && stationCount == 4) {
            paths.add(new ArrayList<>(currentPath));
            return;
        }

        visited[position].set(stationCount);
        currentPath.add(new int[]{x, y});

        for (int[] dir : directions) {
            int newX = x + dir[0];
            int newY = y + dir[1];
            int newPosition = newX * cols + newY;

            if (newX >= 0 && newX < rows && newY >= 0 && newY < cols && !visited[newPosition].get(stationCount)
                    && matrix[newX][newY] != 1) {
                int newStationCount = stationCount + (matrix[newX][newY] == 2 ? 1 : 0);

                if (newStationCount <= 4) {
                    dfs(matrix, newX, newY, newStationCount, visited, directions, currentPath, paths);
                }
            }
        }

        visited[position].clear(stationCount);
        currentPath.remove(currentPath.size() - 1);
    }

    public static int[][] readArrayFromFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            int rows = scanner.nextInt();
            int cols = scanner.nextInt();
            int[][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
            return matrix;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read array from file: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to modified my code. I'm running out of ideas and even logic that can make my code work. The correct number of possible path should be 17,282.

Comment: I put together [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/0yLfwu1e/) that renders [the following texture map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxAEV.png). Maybe you can add the image to your post to make the path more readable?

Answer (score 0):

the code you are using is DFS, deep-first search instead of BFS.

And your code is almost correct by the means of DFS, however your use of the "visited" parameter is not correct, which is the cause of the whole algorithm's wrong. The "visited" parameter is usually a map of your visited nodes, and better to be a bool matrix same as the original graph (your 2D array), because you want to **uniquely** mark the nodes you have visited. However you converted the position into a single value:

```
int position = x * cols + y;
```

which can not **uniquely** mark the nodes you have visited. just for example:

```
1*20 + 0
```

is the same as

```
0*20 + 20
```

but they are two different positions in the graph...

So in your case, you can use:

```
boolean[][] visited = new boolean[rows][cols];
```

to track your visited nodes. And your code can be refactored to this:

```
    public static List<List<int[]>> findPossiblePaths(int[][] matrix) {
            int rows = matrix.length;
            int cols = matrix[0].length;
            boolean[][] visited = new boolean[rows][cols];
            int[][] directions = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};

            List<List<int[]>> paths = new ArrayList<>();
            List<int[]> currentPath = new ArrayList<>();
            dfs(matrix, 0, 0, 0, visited, directions, currentPath, paths);
            return paths;
    }

    private static void dfs(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int stationCount, boolean[][] visited, int[][] directions,
                            List<int[]> currentPath, List<List<int[]>> paths) {
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int cols = matrix[0].length;

        if (x == rows - 1 && y == cols - 1 && stationCount == 4) {
            paths.add(new ArrayList<>(currentPath));
            return;
        }

        visited[x][y]=true;
        currentPath.add(new int[]{x, y});

        for (int[] dir : directions) {
            int newX = x + dir[0];
            int newY = y + dir[1];

            if (newX >= 0 && newX < rows && newY >= 0 && newY < cols && !visited[newX][newY]
                    && matrix[newX][newY] != 1) {
                int newStationCount = stationCount + (matrix[newX][newY] == 2 ? 1 : 0);

                if (newStationCount <= 4) {
                    dfs(matrix, newX, newY, newStationCount, visited, directions, currentPath, paths);
                }
            }
        }

        visited[x][y]=false;
        currentPath.remove(currentPath.size() - 1);
    }
```

And another suggestion is that you can make the matrix, directions, and visited parameters as class member variables instead of parameters, which can make your dfs function's signature simpler.